# Как разделить вектор на два по итератору

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, операции

Есть вектор `std::vector<int> From`;
В нем `10^9` элементов.
И есть `auto iter=std::next(lblock.begin(), 10000);`
Нужно разделить вектор на два вектора по итератору;
Например, создать вектор `std::vector<int> Left`, переместить в него элементы до итератора. Тогда в `From` останется правая часть.
Как это грамотно сделать с точки зрения скорости и памяти, на ваш взгляд?

Comment: *Оставаясь в рамках стандарта*? Копирование, скажем, `assign`, плюс `erase`.

Comment: смотря, что потом с этим вектором/векторами нужно делать. Возможно [span](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span) поможет (если компилятор не поддерживает 20 стандарт, то всегда можно использовать gls::span или что то самописное).

Comment: Я бы подумал не лучше ли  `std::list` или `std::valarray`  вместо вектора?...

Comment: при таких размерах, std::list будет иметь много накладных расходов. То есть, на каждый int (4 байта) нужно ещё два указателя (плюс 16 байт). std::valarray - он вообще то для другого. Хотя он и реализует концепцию, схожую на span

Comment: не вижу особой проблемы хранить все в одном векторе, и все операции производить с итераторами. Но если необходимо все-таки разбить - то для вектора лучше создавать не Left, а Right, и "вытаскивать" элементы с конца (pop_back), т.к. удаление из середины очень накладно.